# After Installing Bitdefender Window System Boot is too slow

Tags: windows-10, boot, anti-virus, bitdefender

### Slow Boot after Installation of Bitdefender Total Security 2021:

I have installed **Bitdefender Total Security 2021** a week ago. And I am now having a problem with my **System's boot**. I am now using **Windows 10 Pro 64bit**. When I boot my PC It takes up to a minute to completely boot up.

Advice welcomed!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I solved my Problem by Running a Full scan on the Advice of [This Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1662456/1430641)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is a common problem with bitdefender security software. They slow up the system in total. That means slow boot and ram hogging. But, this also have a positive side, by providing your system best security. You can try the following tips, they help a lot:

1. You should run a complete system scan. This process, when run for the first time, take approximately 6 hours, But in this process it makes a index of your files and their checksum values etc. It will take much less reources the next time you scan. This also helps in faster boot and reducing memory hog.
2. you can exclude the programs you use every day and which are not prone to a malware attack, like google chrome etc.
3. You can exclude common directories that you use regularly. Please note that don't exclude folders where you download files

Point 2 and 3 are like trading security with improved performance, so apply them carefully. Hopefully this helps but it is be guaranteed it will fasten up your boot. You can also try removing unnecessary programs from startup list. You can edit startup list in task manageer

Comment: That "6 Hr" value was the time it took on my computer, it might greatly vary based on your hardware and amount of your data

Comment: Thanks, After Running a Full Scan it took up to 8 Hours for me. And Now slightly My boot is a little bit faster now! Anyway Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Do you know the Answer for this one, [Zoom Not Allowing me to change my Microphone](https://superuser.com/q/1662901/1430641)