# Zoom Not Allowing me to change my Microphone

Tags: audio, microphone, windows-server-2016, zoom-meeting, input-device

### Zoom Not Allowing me to change my Microphone

I am currently using a **Windows Server 2016** for connecting on **Zoom**. But, My Zoom says "*If you cannot hear your voice, select a different microphone*". When I try to select a different microphone. Dropdown is not selectable *(I think my dropdown is disabled)*. I don't know how to change my Microphone inside Zoom. I searched the internet a lot, but I didn't find anything that work's in my case!

**Attachments:**

[image: Here is a Screenshot of my Zoom]
[image: Here is my Audio Input's ( I am having 4 Audio Inputs)]

### This is the problem that I having now:

[image: This is my Exact Problem]
[image: This is what zoom says]
It says Please select a different device and try again. But I can't change the dropdown because it's disabled. I don't know why!

### This is what I want to achieve (I want to achieve this In my Windows Server 2016):

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

---

### Latest Update: Comparision between my Windows 10 Pc and Windows Server 2016

[image: Comparision between my Windows 10 Pc and Windows Server 2016]

If anyone knows, Plz help me

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Based on your list of devices you only have one potential audio device, but you have red text, over the drop down list so I can’t tell what’s listed.  It’s unclear what your question or problem is

Comment: Sorry, Bro, I have updated the Screenshot and Problem window of my Zoom and my Main Problem is Zoom's Microphone dropdown is not selectable (not changeable). Now it's empty as shown in screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked for microphone malfunction? If a device is malfunctioning, zoom do not includes that in list. And as the @ramhound has pointed you have only one potential audio device. So the chances of my claim to be correct is quite high. Zoom isn't allowing to change microphone because for it, you are having no microphone in working condition.

Also, the [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1NK3.jpg) and [fourth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sftz1.jpg) screenshot supports my claim.

You should try troubleshooting your microphone. Follow the step mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-microphone-problems-5f230348-106d-bfa4-1db5-336f35576011)

If the troubleshooting fails and the problem still persists, you can try one of the following things:-

1. Try upgrading or downgrading you device drivers
2. Use [WO Mic](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-smartphone-windows-microphone/). It acts similarly to DroidCam which you were using. It makes your mobile act as a microphone. I hadn't tried it myself, but it should work. If it doesn't use any of its alternatives.
3. If this happened after a certain event like windows upgrade or a program install, and before that event the mic was working fine, try undoing it.
4. You should consider buying a new microphone.

If the mic is properly installed, then you will need to figure out whether zoom is causing problem or the problem starts from windows. You can do this by checking if other programs accept input from that device or not.

If the problem is on windows side, check how is the device connected - If the device is connected through Wifi, it is possible that firewall blocks the connection. You can follow the steps mentioned [here](http://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1081611/%7E/adding-exceptions-to-the-windows-firewall) to make an exeption. For an example, as the OP told me, he uses vMix. vMix makes connection through TCP port 10349 and TCP port 443 (as mentioned [here](https://www.vmix.com/knowledgebase/article.aspx/125/vmix-call-firewall-requirements)). So he needs to make exeption for these ports

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't help me. I had checked all these. But, it won't work for me. In my Windows 10 PC, my Input is shown. But, in my Windows Server, it is not shown. I have updated my question. Plz checkout! Anyway thanks for responding.

Comment: Now, there could be 2 possible things, - 1. The problem is on windows server 2016's side, 2. The problem is on Zoom side. Did you test your mic with any other application? Did it send data to that application?

Comment: I have tested on my server with my NDI's LINE Input (My Mic Audio Input). Which is properly installed in my server but it doesn't show my Input as a Recording device. But, also In my Windows 10 Pc, I have installed NDI LINE Input (My Audio Input). Which works fine on it. But, My Server doesn't do like that! Plz, Help!

Comment: Also, Plz check out the lastly added [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFg26.jpg). Which is a comparison between my PC and my Server.

Comment: that means the error is on windows side. How is your mic connected, wifi, bluetooth or directly plugged in?

Comment: If the mic is connected through WiFi, it is possible that a firewall rule is blocking it

Comment: Yes, I am streaming to My NDI Audio LINE Input through vMix (A Live Streaming software using WiFi to Stream LIVE. Also, NDI Uses WiFi to receive the Audio). But, I have turned off the Windows FireWall for Domain, Private, Public Networks for some of my Personal Reasons. Bonus: And I am not using any AntiVirus.

Comment: Then probably your firewall is blocking your connection. No - I don't ask you to turn off your firewall. You just need to make an exeption for vMix. I found out [Here](https://www.vmix.com/knowledgebase/article.aspx/125/vmix-call-firewall-requirements) that vMix uses TCP port 10349 and TCP port 443. You need to make a new rule in windows firewall or whichever firewall you use allowing vMix to connect. for windows firewall, you could use steps mentioned [here](http://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1081611/~/adding-exceptions-to-the-windows-firewall)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me! Plz update your answer and I will accept it as Best Answer! And again thank you for your patience and Response! I have upvoted your all comments and answers and questions!